# check directory path for symbols range and ".." up directory sign

Tags: regex, path, preg-match

I try to build RegExp to validate(preg_match) some path string for two following rules:

1. path must consists only symbols from given range `[a-zA-z0-9-_\///\.]`
2. path will not consist an up directory sequence ".."

this is a correct path example: `/user/temp`

and the bad one: `/../user`

**UPD:**
`/user/temp.../foo`  will also be correct (thanks to *Laurence Gonsalves*)

Comment: Is `/user/foo..bar/baz` considered valid?

Comment: Yes it is, ..foo/bar, /foo..bar/baz is CORRECT path example, thanks for your note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
$right_path = '/user/temp';
$wrong_path = '/../user';
$almost_wrong_path = 'foo/abc../bar';
$almost_right_path = 'foo/../bar';

$pattern = '#^(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\/])[-\w.\\/]+$#';
var_dump(preg_match($pattern, $right_path)); // 1
var_dump(preg_match($pattern, $wrong_path)); // 0
var_dump(preg_match($pattern, $almost_wrong_path)); // 1
var_dump(preg_match($pattern, $almost_right_path)); // 0
```

I've actually built this pattern in three steps:

1) the first rule given said that only symbols allowed in the string are `0-9`, `a-zA-Z`, `_` (underscore), `-` (hyphen), `.` (dot) and both slashes (`/` and `\`). First three positions can be expressed with a shortcut (`\w`), others require a character class:

```
[-\w.\\/]
```

Note two things here: 1) hyphen should be either the first or the last symbol in the character class (otherwise it's treated as a metacharacter used to define a range); 2) both dot and forward slash are not escaped yet (backslash is escaped, though; it's too powerful to be left alone, even within `[...]` subexpression).

2) now we have to make sure that the pattern does indeed cover the whole string. We do it with so-called anchors - `^` for beginning of the string, `$` for the end. And, not to forget that our string may consist of one or more allowed symbols (this expressed with `+` quantifier). So the pattern becomes this:

```
^[-\w.\\/]+$
```

3) one last thing - we have to prevent using `../` and `..\` (preceded by `/` or `\` - or not, if `..[/\\]` sequence begins the string) as well.

The easiest way of expressing this rule is using so-called '[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)' test. It's written within (?!...) subexpression, and (in this case) describes the following idea: 'make sure that sequence of zero or more symbols is not followed by "slash-two dots-slash" sequence':

```
^(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\/])[-\w.\\/]+$
```

One last thing is actually placing the pattern into `preg_match` function: as we use `/` symbol within the regex, we can just choose another set of delimiters. In my example, I chose '#':

```
$pattern = '#^(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\/])[-\w.\\/]+$#';
```

See? It's real easy. ) You just have to start from small things and gradually develop them.