# Regex on directory for linux

Tags: ruby, regex, linux

I have tried the regex from the answer of this question: [check directory path for symbols range and ".." up directory sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260371/check-directory-path-for-symbols-range-and-up-directory-sign)

Which was not working for me.  If I passed my script a directory like this "/home/local/NKU/dixonc3/test/" it would not match the regex.

So I just tried to start out with something simple such as if a directory starts with a slash / or a tilde ~ it will pass.

```
^[~/].*$
```

even when I use this as my regex in the code below if I pass it a ~ tilde it gives me an error

```
./rename.rb:23:in `exists?': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
    from ./rename.rb:23:in `rename'
    from ./rename.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

Below is my Ruby code

```
currDir = ""
# 
# regex is from stack overflow question:
#dirRegex = Regexp.new '^(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\/])[-\w.\\/]+$'
dirRegex = Regexp.new '^[~/]*$'
if ARGV.length == 1 && ($1.to_s.match dirRegex)
  currDir = $1
  puts $1
  puts "#{currDir}"
  puts ARGV.length
else
  currDir = "./"
  puts $1
  puts "#{currDir}"
  puts ARGV.length
end
```

Comment: Can you show the line 23 ? I think the problem relies on this line.

Comment: You have a `nil` value somewhere, as Alex asked please post the line with the `exists?` method call in it. Also, you can change the regex to `dirRegex = /^[~/]/`, shorter notation and there is no need for the `.*$` part (which says 'anything else until the end').

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is matching on a single character (`~` or `/` or nothing). It should be:

```
dirRegex = Regexp.new '^[~/].*$'
```

To match on an opening character of `~` or `/` and the rest.